# AnyObject? does not have a member named 'objectAtIndex'

Tags: swift, xcode6-beta6

Got a error on (Xcode6 BETA 6) if a try to get an object of string:

```
let jsonString : String = "[{\"name\":[\"Fred\",\"John\"],\"age\":21},{\"name\":\"Bob\",\"age\":35}]"

let myData:NSData? = jsonString.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding, allowLossyConversion: true)

var jsonResult:NSArray = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(myData!, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers, error: nil) as NSArray

println(jsonResult.objectAtIndex(0).objectForKey("name").objectAtIndex(0))
```

print never get called, cause the error. Anyone a idea?

Comment: It prints 'Fred' using Xcode6 beta5. No errors or crashes

Comment: Crashes on Xcode6 BETA 6!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Getting value from NSDictionary or NSArray return AnyObject object. So you should type cast to appropriate type. Try this

```
println(((jsonResult.objectAtIndex(0) as NSDictionary).objectForKey("name") as NSArray).objectAtIndex(0))
```

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest creating one or more classes and deserializing that JSON, to better access to the data and avoiding mistakes when accessing.

By the way by making data types more explicit it works:

```
let dict = jsonResult.objectAtIndex(0) as NSDictionary
let array = dict["name"] as NSArray

println(array.objectAtIndex(0))
```

Answer (score 1):

Another option would be to cast `jsonResult` to an `Array<AnyObject>` and use `subscript` syntax to get necessary value

```
let jsonString : String = "[{\"name\":[\"Fred\",\"John\"],\"age\":21},{\"name\":\"Bob\",\"age\":35}]"
let myData:NSData? = jsonString.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding, allowLossyConversion: true)
var jsonResult: AnyObject = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(myData!, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers, error: nil);

if let lJsonArray = jsonResult as? Array<AnyObject> {
    println(lJsonArray[0].objectForKey("name")[0])
}
```